# Depth buffer as texture - "D3D11 ERROR: The Format is invalid when creating a View"

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11, depth-buffer

I am trying to use depth buffer as an texture for second pass in my shader.

According to [official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205074(v=vs.85).aspx) (*"Reading the Depth-Stencil Buffer as a Texture"* paragraph), I've set `D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC.Format` to `DXGI_FORMAT_R24G8_TYPELESS` (as it was `DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT` earlier, when I was not using depth buffer as texture):

```
D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC descDepth;
ZeroMemory(&descDepth, sizeof(descDepth));
descDepth.Width = width;
descDepth.Height = height;
descDepth.MipLevels = 1;
descDepth.ArraySize = 1;
descDepth.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R24G8_TYPELESS; //normally it was DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT
descDepth.SampleDesc.Count = antiAliasing.getCount();
descDepth.SampleDesc.Quality = antiAliasing.getQuality();
descDepth.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
descDepth.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL | D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
descDepth.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
descDepth.MiscFlags = 0;

ID3D11Texture2D* depthStencil = NULL;
result = device->CreateTexture2D(&descDepth, NULL, &depthStencil);
```

The `results` succeeded. Then I tried to create shader resource view for my buffer:

```
D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC shaderResourceViewDesc;
//setup the description of the shader resource view
shaderResourceViewDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32_FLOAT;
shaderResourceViewDesc.ViewDimension = antiAliasing.isOn() ? D3D11_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2DMS : D3D11_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
shaderResourceViewDesc.Texture2D.MostDetailedMip = 0;
shaderResourceViewDesc.Texture2D.MipLevels = 1;

//create the shader resource view.
device->CreateShaderResourceView(depthStencil, &shaderResourceViewDesc, &depthStencilShaderResourceView);
```

Unfortunately, that generates an error:

> D3D11 ERROR: ID3D11Device::CreateShaderResourceView: The Format (0x29,
>   R32_FLOAT) is invalid, when creating a View; it is not a fully
>   qualified Format castable from the Format of the Resource (0x2c,
>   R24G8_TYPELESS). [ STATE_CREATION ERROR #127:
>   CREATESHADERRESOURCEVIEW_INVALIDFORMAT]
>
> D3D11 ERROR: ID3D11Device::CreateShaderResourceView: Returning E_INVALIDARG,
>   meaning invalid parameters were passed. [ STATE_CREATION ERROR #131:
>   CREATESHADERRESOURCEVIEW_INVALIDARG_RETURN]

I was also trying with `DXGI_FORMAT_R24G8_TYPELESS`, `DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT` and `DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM` as `shaderResourceViewDesc.Format`.

**Where is the problem?** I was following the documentation and I do not see it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The formats `DXGI_FORMAT_R24G8_TYPELESS` and `DXGI_FORMAT_R32_FLOAT` are not 'cast compatible'. That typeless format is only compatible with `DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT`, `DXGI_FORMAT_R24_UNORM_X8_TYPELESS`, and `DXGI_FORMAT_X24_TYPELESS_G8_UINT`

`DXGI_FORMAT_R32_TYPELESS` is compatible with both `DXGI_FORMAT_D32_FLOAT` and `DXGI_FORMAT_R32_FLOAT`

Comment: So a `_TYPELESS` format is pretty much a floating point type isn't it? If the type is known why call it typeless? It's just that this always confused me. It seems that the point in `TYPELESS` is that we don't know if it's for Depth Buffer or Color Buffer and/or whether it's normalized.

Comment: ``_TYPELESS`` is just a method for deferring telling the driver the actual format. What the format actually is must be decided by the time the GPU tries to use it. Each video card vendor has different schemes for laying out the various channels. For example, ``R32_FLOAT`` is usually one plane of pixels 4 bytes each. The ``R24G8`` formats could be one plane of 4 bytes per pixel -or- it could be two planes (4 bytes per pixel with one unused, and another plane of 1 byte per pixel) -or- it could be some other thing.